# Telnet rs232 using scpi :s:gui:c

Tags: rs232

I have some problems in using **SCPI:S:GUI:C** language, because I'm just a programmer but I need to deal with some devices connecting with RS232 in Flash.

I have this machine which connects to the pc via Rs232 -USB.

I want to send some commands through Telnet (or any other hyperTerminal) and get some response.
(I am using this Serial Port Utility to send commands over)

Serial transmission parameters
It is asynchronous serial protocol with the parameters as shown below:

LP Parametr       Opis

1  Speed (bits/s) 19200

2  Data (bits)    8

3  Parity         No

4  Start (bit)    1

5  Stop (bit)     1

In the machine spec, the Command syntax to get machine status is: „:S:GUI:C?$0A”

anyone knows how to send and get it to response something?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any terminal program of your choice. I usually recommand PuTTY or (especially if some debugging is required hterm).

I think you get stuck with the $0A. Consider this to be "LineFeed" which can usually be achieved by pressing "Enter". So do the following:

1. Open the connection to your device e.g. in hterm
2. Type: :S:GUI:C? (including the ":" and the "?")
3. Press Enter

You should get something back. If you don't, post how you connected your device to your PC and details about the device.

Comment: One end of the device is connected with Rs232, and the pc side is an USB com port12. I use Serial Port Utility by darkwood. I type exactly :S:GUI:C? , but still doesn't have any response. The program shows the connection is opened.

Comment: Hmmm .. do you have any documentation for this device you could show? Apart from that, try without the leading ":", try just GUI:C?.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you have set a baudrate of 9600 instead of 19200. You need to set the baudrate first, then connect.

Comment: Actually quite weird, i thought i set the baudrate on the left side panel, but seems not really set the correct baudrate right?

Comment: I have attached more images for the device spec, thanks for your help!

Comment: As I said, you need to set the value first, then press the Connect/Whatever Button. Now you will need to disconnect, set the baudrate correctly, then connect again. It MUST say 19200 at the bottom after you are connected. Try a different terminal program. I would recommend PuTTY for a first try (http://www.chipkin.com/using-putty-for-serial-com-connections-hyperterminal-replacement/)